# Reusable component using React Redux mapStateToProps

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

A *React* component `OilBarrel` connected my *redux* store to create a container `OilBarrelContainer`:

```
// ---- component

class OilBarrel extends Component {
  render() {
     let data = this.props.data;
     ...
  }
}

// ---- container

function mapStateToProps(state) {
  let data = state.oilbarrel.data;
  ...
}

const OilBarrelContainer = connect(mapStateToProps)(OilBarrel)

// ---- reducer

const oilbarrel = (state = {}, action) => {
  let data = state.data;
}

const storeFactory = (server = false, initialState = {}) => {
    return applyMiddleware(...middleware(server))(createStore)(
        combineReducers({oilbarrel, otherReducer1, otherReducer2}),
        initialState
    )
}
```

I find it strange that `mapStateToProps()` receives the top level state object (the entire state of the application), requiring me to traverse `state.oilbarrel.data`, when the reducer (conveniently) only receives the branch of the state that belongs to this component.

This limits the ability to reuse this container without knowing where it fits into the state hierarchy. Am I doing something wrong that my `mapStateToProps()` is receiving the full state?

Comment: how does the placement of the component alter the state hierarchy?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is the `mapStateToProps` behavior. You have to think redux state as a single source of truth (by the way, that is what it really is) independently of the components you have in project. There is no way out, you have to know the exactly hierarchy of you especific data in the state to pass it to your container component.

Comment: Thanks, so if I want another OilBarrel component at a different place in the state hierarchy, then must I create a new container for it?

Comment: why do you will put another OilBarrel in another place of state? an array of OilBarrel's doesn't fit in this situation?

Comment: No. You could render `<OilBarrel id={2} />`, and use the `ownProps` argument in `mapState` to look up the right value based on that ID.

Answer (score 2):

No this is intentional, because you may want to use other parts of the state inside your component. One option is to keep the selector (mapStateToProps) in a separate file from your component, which will help you reuse the selector, if you app is very large and complex you can also checkout libraries such as reselect which helps you make your selectors more efficient.

Answer (score 2):

Dan Abramov offers a solution for this in his advanced redux course under [Colocating Selectors with Reducers](https://egghead.io/lessons/javascript-redux-colocating-selectors-with-reducers).

The idea is that for every reducer, there is a selector, and the selector is only aware of it's reducer structure. The selectors for higher level reducers, wrap the lower level reducer, with their part of the state, and so on.

The example was taken from the course's [github](https://github.com/gaearon/todos/tree/10-colocating-selectors-with-reducers/src/reducers):

In the todos reducer file:

```
export const getVisibleTodos = (state, filter) => {
  switch (filter) {
    case 'all':
      return state;
    case 'completed':
      return state.filter(t => t.completed);
    case 'active':
      return state.filter(t => !t.completed);
    default:
      throw new Error(`Unknown filter: ${filter}.`);
  }
};
```

In the main reducer file:

```
export const getVisibleTodos = (state, filter) =>
  fromTodos.getVisibleTodos(state.todos, filter);
```

Now you can get every part of your state without knowing the structure. However, it adds a lot of boilerplate.